# Regex to delete lines containing 3 or more occurences of a specific charachter

Tags: regex

I have a long file that look like this:

11A222BB
11AA222B
11AA22BC
1AAA22BB
1AA2A3BB
A1A2A3BA

I would like to delete all lines that contains 3 or more occurences of the letter A, so in this example:

11A222BB
11AA222B
11AA22BC
1AAA22BB - to delete
1AA2A3BB - to delete
A1A2A3BA - to delete

can anyone help me with this? any help will be apreciated.

Comment: A file ? How do you plan on reading that file ?

Comment: Generally, to match the bad line it's `^(?:[^A]*A){3}.*`

Comment: @PatMyron yes it also should be deleted

Comment: @sln i use notepad++ to search for the lines. your regex is good but it matches with multiple lines also, which it should not. I tried ^(?:[^A]*A){3}.*$ but it still matches with multiple lines.

Comment: `(?m)^(?:[^A\r\n]*A){3}.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following pattern.

`/(.*A.*){3,}/g`

[Working example](https://regex101.com/r/IvWQ2s/3)

Comment: Why are you using word boundaries?

Comment: @Toto thanks! I just read this - *delete all lines that contains 3 or more occurences*